# Why initialize a variable that is immediately set in a loop?

Tags: matlab

Part of a `while` loop has some pieces:

```
k = 1.6;  %%give an initial k
k1 = 1.5;
l = 0.01
while abs((k-k1)/k)>0.00001
    k1=k;
        k=k-l;
    ...
end
```

1. Why bother setting `k1 = 1.5` when it is immediately set to `k`. Later in the loop it only changes `k` and `l`, not `k1`.

Also, later in the programme after this loop, they put

```
k = 0.1:0.01:3;
```

2. Does this replace the `k=1.6` ... or did the loop make `k` into a vector?
3. Finally, if this intuition that `k` a vector is correct, what does

   k = k - l

in a loop mean?

$ k_{t+1} = k_t - l $

Comment: If you don't initialize `k1` outside of the loop, what do you think will happen when `while abs((k-k1)/k)>0.00001` is first executed as the loop is entered? It's hard to say much about your other questions without seeing the full code. And don't assume that other people's code is correct, bug-free, or well-written.

Comment: Oh! great point thank you @horchler, it will not run because k1 is not yet defined

Comment: @horchler, So um want me to post the full code?  Or you answered my primary question, so want to copy as an answer so I can accept it? ... I also would like to accept so i can get 2 points so i can get upvote permission(:

Comment: The first question is a bit basic for an answer – it's fundamental Matlab. I usually comment rather than answer such questions. If you want to improve your questions and get others to help you, you can try posting your code – or better a simple example that demonstrates the issue. You're also welcome to answer (and accept) your own questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. As mentioned k needs to have some value before the while loop is meaningful and can be initiated.
2. Yes that replaces k. Whenever there is an equals sign, the variable is defined anew.
3. K is not a vector in the part of the code that says k = k - l. That code snippet means that k is now equal to what k was before minus l, e.g. if k was 5 before that line and l is 2, then k is now 3.